# Data coming from frontend duplicates in backend twice

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
class Signup extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
    
        this.newUser();
    };

    newUser = (e) => {
        fetch("http://localhost:4000/signup", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <input
                onChange={this.onChange}
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Username"
              />
              <input
                onChange={this.onChange}
                type="text"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Email"
              />
              <input
                onChange={this.onChange}
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <button onClick={this.newUser}>Sign Up</button>
              <p className="message">Do you have an account? <a href="login">Login</a></p>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Node.js

```js
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
});
```

I'm trying to get a signup working with reactjs and nodejs but the data I get in nodejs are duplicated twice.

I'm sending a request of my username, email and password from frontend and in the backend it duplicates. For example the data I send gets sent twice in backend. If I were to send {username: 'hello', email: hello@gmail.com, password: 2323} in backend console.log(req.body) it would come twice {username: 'hello', email: hello@gmail.com, password: 2323}, {username: 'hello', email: hello@gmail.com, password: 2323}.

Anyone might have an idea why this is happening, would help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you have the button click executing `this.newUser` and the function `onSubmit` is also triggered when you click the button.

I'd suggest leaving the  `onSubmit` in the form tag, and remove the `onClick` in the button.